# Recursive tree traversal adding result to nested dict in python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

I am trying to make a recursive traversal over a tree. My `class Node` has method `get_children` which I use to understand that traversal should be stopped. The difficulty I am facing is that my resulting dict should present a nested structure with results of traversal. And if the traversal itself is trivial, appending children elements is not (I tried to solve it with dfs/bfs)

My example tree looks like this:

[image]

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, parent=None, lft=None, rght=None, children=[]):
        self.value = 'random_value'
        self.parent = parent
        # lft and rght probably don't make much sense(cause node can have >2 children) but they are present in the Node structure
        self.lft = lft
        self.rght = rght
        self.children = children


    def get_children(self, node):
        return self.children


n1 = Node()
n2 = Node()
n3 = Node()
n4 = Node()
n5 = Node()
n6 = Node()
n7 = Node()
n8 = Node()
# adding connections as on the picture above
n1.lft = n2
n1.rght = n3
n1.children = [n2, n3]

n2.parent = n1

n3.parent = n1
n3.rght = n4
n3.children = [n4]

n4.parent = n3
n4.rght = n5
n4.children = [n5]

n5.parent = n4
n5.lft = n7
n5.rght = n6
n5.children = [n6,n7,n8]

n6.parent = n5
n7.parent = n5
n8.parent = n5
```

My dfs and bfs allow me to traverse the tree. But I also have to pass some path to the current place in resulting dict where to insert new children values and it is getting really cumbersome.

My attempts:

```
# try bfs
@staticmethod
def breadth_first_search(root):
    import collections

    res_dict = {
        "node": {
            "name": root.name,
            "children": []
        }
    }

    visited = set()
    queue = collections.deque([root])

    current = ["node", "children"]

    while queue:
        vertex = queue.popleft()

        for idx, neighbour in enumerate(vertex.get_children()):
            # logic
            # gets difficult to track the nested levels in the resulting dict, now it always appends to the ["node"]["children"] and don't pay attention to the nested levels
            res_dict["node"]["children"].append(neighbour)

            if neighbour not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbour)
                queue.append(neighbour)

# try with dfs
@classmethod
def dfs(node):
    if not node.get_children():
        return node
    else:
        for idx, child_node in enumerate(node.get_children()):
            # logic
            # gets difficult to track the nested levels in the dict

            return Node.dfs(child_node)
```

Results I want to achieve:

```
 desired_dict = {
        # root
        "node": n1.value,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": n2.value,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "name": n3.value,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": n4.value,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": n5.value,
                                "children": [
                                  {
                                    "name": n6.value,
                                    "children": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "name": n7.value,
                                    "children": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "name": n8.value,
                                    "children": []
                                  }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

How to recursively traverse the tree and while traversing create `dict` with structure as in `desired_dict`?

[REPL](https://repl.it/repls/CloudyAutomaticRelationaldatabase)

Comment: Your nodes don’t hold references to the children; they are just strings. If you are going to do this you’ll need to have the nodes in a dict so they can be found with a string key.

Comment: @MarkMeyer fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DFS for the task. You need to pass a dict to the DFS to fill it with current node of the tree. And before calling next level of DFS create a new dict and put it into `children` array of the current one

The idea in a python code:

```
def dfs(node, ndict):
    ndict["value"] = node.value
    ndict["children"] = []
    for idx, child in enumerate(node.get_children()):
        child_dict = {}
        dfs(child, child_dict)
        ndict["children"].append(child_dict)
```